# Blueprint Priority problem with items containing the same path and title

Tags: 2013, blueprint

I was under the impression that it's possible to inherit from two parent publications that contain items with the same path and title values.   I believed that this is allowed because there is a priority setting when configuring blueprinting within the new publication.

From the docs:

> If a Child Publication has more than one Parent Publication, you can
>   define priority in the Publication properties BluePrinting tab to
>   determine where the Publication shares an item from.

However i'm trying to implement this in my CME and i'm getting errors when attempting to save the new publication because of matching item names and paths from the parent publications.

> The following items cause title conflicts in a child Publication:
>   Component 'test1',Component 'test2',Component ' .. etc'

Note: I've tried to save the publication first with 1 parent, then edit the blueprint structure to add the second publication, but this also causes the same error to be raised.

I suspect this may be by design, but i'm wondering if there is a way around this.

Comment: What if the components had different schemas each with their own templates? They then couldn't be interchangeable as valid component presentations on a given page. Does that change the expectation this would work? :-)

Comment: No it doesn't.  I understand the complexity of what my question means, i've updated my question with the documentation from SDL, which certainly gives the impression of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Ah, well the docs also have "If one chain of Publications leading to *the parent item* is shorter than all other chains, the Child Publication shares from the shortest chain" (emphasis mine). This really has to be the same item shared to both publications, rather than two components with the same path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those Items have the same name and location but were created in different publications right?

In that case from a functional point of view those items are different and will be consumed from the same publication (The one that you are creating inheriting from both), that is the reason the Blueprint won't allow that, which is the correct and expected behavior

I would try the following things:

1--> If the main folder containing those components was created at the same publication level, just rename the parent folder of the Items in one publication, so you create two different locations, one per publication

2--> If the main folder was created in a parent publication inherited by those publications, relocate the problematic items to a different folder/set of folders

3 --> If you are having same issue with pages (hope not) you will have to relocate the pages also, but that will affect the web structure of the existing apps generated from that publication

Comment: hi miguel, you're a good man, but the content structure is not this flexible, it would require days worth of renaming and then renaming back. - thanks for your notes though :)

Comment: Yep, pretty sure is not that easy but at some point you will have to refactor the current folder structure, good luck with that man

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of one of the items?

Blueprint rules will indeed not allow this, priorities are only used to decide which publication is the "nearest Owner".

Comment: if it's impossible to have the same item name / path in a parent, i don't understand what you mean by 'nearest owner'

Comment: I think that's "shortest BluePrint chain" or the closest publication to a shared item. Think free-falling items and find the one that bonks you in the head first. :-P

Comment: up voting your comment for the brilliant analogy :)

Answer (score 2):

The priority is used when an item is present in more than one ancestor publication. It is not used to choose between two distinct items. (As you have discovered, Tridion rightly prevents you from creating a scenario where two items would have to occupy the same place in the BluePrinted structure.)

If you want to use BluePrinting logic for this, you should create the item higher up in the BluePrint, and localize it on each side of the diamond to get the differences you need. You can then use priorities to select the right one further down the BluePrint.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to have inheriting from different publication to achieve language sites.

But at the end,

> **All these Publications and Structure Groups are Folders.**

Similar to windows folder, where we can't create two folders/files with the same name at the same path.

To overcome the problem, as **@Nuno** said change the name of one of the items

Comment: you're right, but i think the priority should manage this, to choose with single item is inherited, i had assumed it did

Comment: Those are different items that are created with different ids. It just happened that had same name, so from a blueprint point of view those items are completely different